# Codeigniter thumbnail array not working

Tags: php, thumbnails, image-uploading

Im doing multiple file uploading, which is working fine.
im getting both images but the other image which is thumnail not getting their given path and also not changing in to thumb size.

I have just issues with thumbnail in **"thumbnail creation start"** area i hope.
check my array and let me know my mistake.

controller codes

```
public function addimage($room_id)
{
    $name_array = array();
    $count = count($_FILES['userfile']['size']);
    foreach($_FILES as $key=>$value)
    for($s=0; $s<=$count-1; $s++) 
    {
        $_FILES['userfile']['name']=$value['name'][$s];
        $_FILES['userfile']['type']    = $value['type'][$s];
        $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] = $value['tmp_name'][$s];
        $_FILES['userfile']['error']       = $value['error'][$s];
        $_FILES['userfile']['size']    = $value['size'][$s];  
        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
        $config['encrypt_name']  = TRUE;
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        $this->upload->do_upload();
        $data = $this->upload->data();
        $name_array[] = $data['file_name']; // get file names for first file

        //thumbnail creation start
        $config1['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $config1['source_image'] = $image['full_path'];
        $config1['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
        $config1['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
        $config1['upload_path'] = './uploads/thumbs/';
        $config1['width'] = 150;
        $config1['height'] = 150;

        $this->load->library('image_lib', $config1);
        $this->image_lib->resize();
        $this->upload->do_upload();
        $data = $this->upload->data();
        $name_array1[] = $data['file_name']; // file names for thumb
        //thumbnail creation end
    }

    $names= implode(',', $name_array);  
    $names2= implode(',', $name_array1);    
    //print_r($names);
    $options = array( 
        'id' => '0',
        'org_image' => $names,
        'thumbnail' => $names2,
        'room_id' => $room_id,
        'created' => '1',
        'status' => '1'
    );

    $this->rooms_model->room_images_insert($options);
    redirect('/admin/rooms', 'location');
} //end of function
```

Comment: **check my array and let me know my mistake.** No We can't !

Comment: Is My Codes are Correct so why thumbnail creation not working ??

Comment: You have any entry in error log ?

Comment: No.
check my codes..i already written this.

Comment: Your problem is in generating path or uploading the image ?

Comment: not in uploading.

just thumbnail image not getting its path and its given size.

Comment: So, the error is displaying the image from its location ?

Comment: yes location and size.

both images saving at same place and the thumb image not changing its size.

Comment: Where did you declare variable $image?

Comment: missed !!
where i should ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
$config1['source_image'] = $image['full_path'];
```

To

```
$config1['source_image'] = $data['full_path'];
```

Also remove the following commented lines

```
$this->image_lib->resize();
//$this->upload->do_upload();
//$data = $this->upload->data();
```

Comment: From Both of your correction now thumb image changing its size but now im getting 3 images. one is thumb and the other 2 is in same original size.why

Comment: now getting 2 images with correct thing. But Still have Path `problem`

Comment: does it work? It is better initialize everytime when you are generating image properly and load library before loop to optimize code.

Comment: Im posting my corrected codes again below..
check last answer..im posting

Answer (score 0):

After you do config for your image i.e., setting your image attributes then you should clear and initizliae the `image_lib` to get effect.

```
$this->image_lib->clear();
$this->image_lib->initialize($config);
$this->image_lib->resize();
```

**Note :**

1. Make sure that you need it for `$config` or `$config1`
2. Make sure that you have the `source_image` path right

Comment: From Both of your correction now thumb image changing its size but now im getting 3 images.
one is thumb and the other 2 is in same original size.why

Comment: Do yo have `do_upload()` any where else ?

Comment: Why you need it twice ? Can you remove one and have a try ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 public function addimage($room_id)
    {
        $name_array = array();
        $count = count($_FILES['userfile']['size']);
        foreach($_FILES as $key=>$value)
        for($s=0; $s<=$count-1; $s++) 
        {
            $_FILES['userfile']['name']=$value['name'][$s];
            $_FILES['userfile']['type']    = $value['type'][$s];
            $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] = $value['tmp_name'][$s];
            $_FILES['userfile']['error']    = $value['error'][$s];
            $_FILES['userfile']['size']    = $value['size'][$s];  
            $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
            $config['encrypt_name']  = TRUE;
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            $this->upload->do_upload();
            $data = $this->upload->data();
            $name_array[] = $data['file_name']; // get file names for first file

  //thumbnail creation start
            $config1['image_library'] = 'gd2';
            $config1['source_image'] = $data['full_path'];
            $config1['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
            $config1['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
            $config1['upload_path'] = './uploads/thumbs/';
            $config1['width'] = 500;
            $config1['height'] = 150;

            $this->load->library('image_lib', $config1);
            $this->image_lib->clear();
            $this->image_lib->initialize($config1);
            $this->image_lib->resize();
            $name_array1[] = $data['file_name']; // get file names for thumb file
    //thumbnail creation end
        }

        $names= implode(',', $name_array);  
        $names2= implode(',', $name_array1);    
        //print_r($names);
            $options = array( 
            'id' => '0',
            'org_image' => $names,
            'thumbnail' => $names2,
            'room_id' => $room_id,
            'created' => '1',
            'status' => '1'
                );

            $this->rooms_model->room_images_insert($options);
            redirect('/admin/rooms', 'location');


    } //end of function
```